# how to make secure database offline

Tags: database, security, web

I am trying to learn about ways of making data secure from hack attacks, and NSA snooping. I read an article in which it says the best way now is to physically separate database that has the most important data and it should be offline.

So my questions to that person would be if i could ask him..

if it's offline how does it connect to internet?

if all OS are somewhat suspicious then what to use...( i've read that windows, linux and mac are compromised...windows may even have built in security holes.) It said that install new os and lock it down. Which means what?

what are other ways to make your user's data truly secure.

Comment: Do you seriously expect to get it all in one answer? A book is a more suitable media type.

Comment: NO i don't but i do expect to get tips and what direction to go to..that would be much help to clueless person like me.

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to use [Linux From Scratch (LFS)](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) and follow the [Hardened LFS (HLFS) guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hlfs/).

This will provide you with a base for a stable and secure operating environment.

From there, you will need to engineer your own open source and peer reviewed database management system (DBMS) that implements [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

This DBMS should probably use some kind of peer to peer mirroring architecture and ensure that all of the data is encrypted using only keys the original data author has created. The keys are never persisted remotely or given to the DBMS and this essentially keeps the data offline, until the encryption key is revealed or compromised.

The peer to peer component can allow for distributed load balancing and also prevent attacks against a specific node to cause denial of service or information leakage or origin tracing. You can accomplish peer to peer data transactions using a distributed hash table and remote lock management techniques (see Microsoft's network mutex implementation).

Once you have all of this developed and audited by a group of professionals, you would want to release it to the world in an open source fashion. You should digitally sign all code modifications and binaries to prevent attackers from embedding vulnerabilities into your code post-release.

After this is done, you can then take that version and have it peer reviewed by the community interested in your product. After a few years, the public should have enough trust in it to widely use it, or completely lose interest after major vulnerabilities or other issues are made known through public disclosure.

Expect years of programming and learning advanced topics with steep learning curves. Hundreds of dollars in books and many late nights spent with a coffee machine are probably an underestimate of what will be required to complete this monumental task.